# Flutter Slider shadow (How to disable , How to change the direction)

Tags: flutter, slider

[snapshot with Slider widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqp4g.png)

Q1.
I want to know how to disable Thumb Shadow.

Q2.
I want to know how to change the direction of Thumb Shadow.
I want to set the direction to RIGHT (not to DOWN).

Please help me.
I use Android studio 4.0 and Flutter 1.22.3.

I googled some code with word "flutter slider thumb shadow"
but I can not find any answer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
          trackHeight: 14,
          thumbColor: Colors.white,
          thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 7),
          trackShape: RectangularSliderTrackShape(),
          valueIndicatorColor: Colors.orange,
          overlayColor: Colors.transparent,
          activeTrackColor: Colors.green,
          activeTickMarkColor: Colors.red,
          inactiveTrackColor: Colors.green,
          inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double val=1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Q1. Shadow off \n Q2. How to change Shadow direction',
            ),
            Container(
              width: 140,
              height: 240,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 3.0,
                child: Slider(
                  value: val,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 2,
                  divisions: 2,
                  onChanged: (double value) {
                    setState (() {
                      val = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You must set the elevation on the thumbShape property, like:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SliderTheme(
          data: const SliderThemeData(               
               thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(elevation: 0),
          ),
          child: Slider(),
```

Comment: In fact, this is the correct answer. To add up, there is also the `pressedElevation` property which you can set to eliminate elevation when the thumb (Slider's circle component) is long pressed. (Also, I've witnessed a minor issue in one device like shadow still being persistent although both properties are set to 0. But in most devices I've had no problem)

Answer (score 3):

you need to make the overlay transparent by the following:

```
    SliderTheme(
           data: SliderThemeData(
        
           overlayColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Slider( ../))
```